# AS3 Is comboBox empty?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got an onChange event in which I'd like to test if a comboBox is empty, if it is, I want to change the colour of the comboBox. I can find a value e.g. "Fred Bloggs" but not test to see if it's empty:

```
if (e.target.selectedItem.label == ""){ // This doesn't work
      trace("EMPTY");
my_color.color = 0x002222;
instructorList.transform.colorTransform = my_color;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **selectedItem** property will be null if no item is selected:

```
comboBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseHandler);

function mouseHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
    if (e.currentTarget.selectedItem == null){ // This doesn't work
        trace("EMPTY");
        my_color.color = 0x002222;
        instructorList.transform.colorTransform = my_color;
    }
}
```

Note the **CHANGE** event won't be fired if there are no items in the ComboBox because it's not possible to 'change' it to anything. Instead, add this test to the **CLICK** handler.

**UPDATE:** Given the new information in the comments below, simply test if the index matches the blank item at the top of the list.

```
    if (e.currentTarget.selectedIndex == 0) {
        trace("EMPTY");
        my_color.color = 0x002222;
        instructorList.transform.colorTransform = my_color;
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I've tried it on label and on data but no change.

Comment: The problem is you're using the wrong EventHandler, I've updated my answer to help.

Comment: The only empty value is at the top of the list. Basically, it's blank until changed. I want to check when it's gone back to blank, if that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were after. I thought you were trying to test if there were no items in the ComboBox. I've updated my answer again to test if the ComboBox has selected the top item (i.e. the blank one).

Answer (score 0):

A flex change event is only dispatched when the **user** initiates a change. If the change is user initiated, it won't be null. If you want to look for a null, try the valueCommit property/event.

Comment: But shouldn't it fire when there is a value and then changed to no value? (Is Flex exactly the same as Flash AS3?)

Comment: @user1203605 Yes, if that's one of the options in your combobox' dataprovider.

Comment: @user1203605 Why don't you compare to comboBox.selectedLabel instead of event.target.selectedItem.label?